# Not able to capture/Extract id generated in response in Post method

Tags: rest-api, rest-assured, rest

I am facing this issue - capture/print the id generated in response

last 2 line are the issue, the moment i take out last 2 line,test get passed[image]

```
public void emp()
{
    
RestAssured.baseURI= "https://dummy.restapiexample.com";
String response=given().log().all().header("Content-Type","application/json")
.body(payload.employee()).when().post("/api/v1/create")
.then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200)
.header("Server", "Apache").extract().response().asString();
System.out.println(response);

JsonPath js = new JsonPath(response);
String id = js.getString("id");
System.out.println(id);
```

HOW TO CAPTURE THE ID =7368, so i can use in put method.i even tried js.getlong.

pls need help urgently